# Pivot and group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I want to do a pivot table to show the solds per category and per client 
and the categories table is like this:

```
code     |  name
-----------------------
100000   | ILUMINACION
980101   | MUEBLES ACCESORIOS DECORATIVO
980102   | MUEBLES ACCESORIOS INTERIOR
980103   | MUEBLES ACCESORIOS ZOCALO
```

All works fine when I do a simple pivot with all elements of the categories table, but the table have near 600 different categories so the result is not very readable, and now what I want is to group by the 2 first digits so the result will be something like: ILUMINACION, MATERIAL ELECTRICO, MUEBLES,ELECTRODOMESTICOS... , doing this it will less categories, doing the pivot much more readable, I try putting a group by in the from clause, but give me error that says "The subquery returned more than one value".

This is my code:

---EDIT----
I tried to simplify as much as posible

First of all the select, with the sums for the pivot(this is not a problema)

```
select cliente,
(
select CASE WHEN cliente!='' then max(c.nombre) else 'CONTADO' end 
from CLIENTES c where c.nif=cliente
),
sum([APARELLAJE MEDIA TENSION_2015]) as [APARELLAJE MEDIA TENSION_2015],
sum([APARELLAJE MEDIA TENSION_2016]) as [APARELLAJE MEDIA TENSION_2016], 
sum([AUTOMATIZACION_2015]) as [AUTOMATIZACION_2015],
sum[AUTOMATIZACION_2016]) as [AUTOMATIZACION_2016],
sum([CANALIZACION_2015]) as [CANALIZACION_2015], 
sum([CANALIZACION_2016]) as [CANALIZACION_2016],
sum([COMPUESTOS_2015]) as [COMPUESTOS_2015], 
sum([COMPUESTOS_2016]) as [COMPUESTOS_2016],
sum([CONDUCTOR_2015]) as [CONDUCTOR_2015], 
sum([CONDUCTOR_2016]) as [CONDUCTOR_2016],
sum([CONEXION_2015]) as [CONEXION_2015], 
sum([CONEXION_2016]) as [CONEXION_2016],
sum([ELECTRODOMESTICOS_2015]) as [ELECTRODOMESTICOS_2015],
sum([ELECTRODOMESTICOS_2016]) as [ELECTRODOMESTICOS_2016],
sum([ENVOLVENTES_2015]) as [ENVOLVENTES_2015],
sum([ENVOLVENTES_2016]) as [ENVOLVENTES_2016],
sum([HERRAMIENTAS_2015]) as [HERRAMIENTAS_2015], 
sum([HERRAMIENTAS_2016]) as [HERRAMIENTAS_2016],
sum([ILUMINACION_2015]) as [ILUMINACION_2015], 
sum([ILUMINACION_2016]) as [ILUMINACION_2016],
sum([INSTRUMENTACION_2015]) as [INSTRUMENTACION_2015], 
sum([INSTRUMENTACION_2016]) as [INSTRUMENTACION_2016],
sum([MATERIAL DE INSTALACION_2015]) as [MATERIAL DE INSTALACION_2015],
sum([MATERIAL DE INSTALACION_2016]) as [MATERIAL DE INSTALACION_2016],
sum([PEQUEÑO MATERIAL_2015]) as [PEQUEÑO MATERIAL_2015], 
sum([PEQUEÑO MATERIAL_2016]) as [PEQUEÑO MATERIAL_2016],
sum([PROTECCION MANDO Y MEDIDA_2015]) as [PROTECCION MANDO Y MEDIDA_2015],
sum([PROTECCION MANDO Y MEDIDA_2016]) as [PROTECCION MANDO Y MEDIDA_2016],
sum([VARIOS_2015]) as [VARIOS_2015], sum([VARIOS_2016]) as [VARIOS_2016]
```

**This is the heart of the matter**

```
from
(
  select c.nif cliente, lac.ImporteLimpio suma,
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
     (
      select case when ca.Codigo like '97%' then 'HERRAMIENTAS'
      else ca.Nombre end from CodigosEstadisticos_ARTICULOS ca
      where ca.Codigo=substring(cea.Codigo,1,2)+'0000'
     )
  +'_'+cast(YEAR(acc.fecalb)as varchar(100))
  from ALBARAN_CLIENTE acc,CodigosEstadisticos_ARTICULOS cca
  group by substring(cca.Codigo,1,2),acc.fecalb
  ) AS SalesRegion

from ALBARAN_CLIENTE ac join LINEAS_ALBARAN_CLIENTE lac on
c.codalb=lac.codalb join ARTICULOS a on a.codart=lac.codart join 
CodigosEstadisticos_ARTICULOS cea on cea.Codigo=a.codigoEstadistico
join CLIENTES c on c.codcli=ac.codcli 
where month(ac.fecalb)<month(getdate()) and(year(ac.fecalb)=year(getdate())
or year(ac.fecalb)=year(getdate())-1

)as p
```

The part of the PIVOT(i don´t think here is any problem)

```
PIVOT
(
SUM(suma) FOR SalesRegion IN
([APARELLAJE MEDIA TENSION_2015],[APARELLAJE MEDIA TENSION_2016],
[AUTOMATIZACION_2015],[AUTOMATIZACION_2016],[CANALIZACION_2015],
CANALIZACION_2016], [COMPUESTOS_2015],[COMPUESTOS_2016],[CONDUCTOR_2015],
CONDUCTOR_2016],[CONEXION_2015],[CONEXION_2016],[ELECTRODOMESTICOS_2015],
[ELECTRODOMESTICOS_2016],[ENVOLVENTES_2015],[ENVOLVENTES_2016],
HERRAMIENTAS_2015],[HERRAMIENTAS_2016],[ILUMINACION_2015],
[ILUMINACION_2016],[INSTRUMENTACION_2015],[INSTRUMENTACION_2016],
[MATERIAL DE INSTALACION_2015],[MATERIAL DE INSTALACION_2016],
[PEQUEÑO MATERIAL_2015],[PEQUEÑO MATERIAL_2016],
[PROTECCION MANDO Y MEDIDA_2015],[PROTECCION MANDO Y MEDIDA_2016],
VARIOS_2015],[VARIOS_2016])
) AS pivottable group by cliente;
```

Comment: Ouch. You should not be scared of using a little bit of white space to format this into something legible. As posted I can't begin to unravel this. I did notice you are using comma separated lists in your from clause. This type of join has been out of favor for close to 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Sean Lange : Yes, i know that using comma in the from is not good and the correct(in my case)  is to use left join, but to do this i need to join 4 tables, when the only thing i need in the last table is the present year and the previous year, surely there is a better way to obtain only the current and the previous year(2016, 2015), but i don´t know.

In terms of the another suggestion, i removed the dynamic query and try to put all more clear and i have separated the code in 3 blocks to center the attention in the important code.
Thanks for your comments and your time.